# Counting the amount of words in a string php

Tags: php, curl

I'm printing a string which contains HTML content from a given url. What I'm trying to do is find out how many words are within the string and how many times they appear.

For example:

today | 1

How | 1

Hello | 1

Code:

```
$string = "Hello how are you today"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code has to do with your question, but you could try [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split it on spaces, then loop over the array and use the words as keys in another array, incrementing each time. If you want to split on any word boundary, use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and split on `\b`. Just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking your $cResult as input:

```
$word_counts = [];

// remove scripts and styles completely, then strip tags
$cResult = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $cResult);
$cResult = preg_replace('#<style(.*?)>(.*?)</style>#is', '', $cResult);
$cResult = strip_tags($cResult);

// strip all characters that are not letters:
$word_array_raw = explode(' ',preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z ]/', ' ', $cResult)); 

// loop through array:
foreach ($word_array_raw as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    if($word) {
        isset($word_counts[$word]) ? $word_counts[$word]++ : $word_counts[$word] = 1;
    }
}

// Array with all stats sorted in descending order:
arsort($word_counts); 

// Output format you wanted:
foreach ($word_counts as $word=>$count) { 
    echo "$word | $count<br>";
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a way to remove html tag names from the result?

Comment: I've tried that. That simply just removed the brackets. I still have the word itself left behind. For example, getElementById.

Comment: This is current output of the code (with strip_tags) run on "visitbirmingham" url:
More | 118
Read | 113
the | 92
Birmingham | 72 ... etc.  No tagnames get through.

Comment: getElementById is not a tagname, but a JS function.  So, I now the code removes js and css from html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  $s = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sit sed do lorem eiusmod tempor";
  $w = preg_split('=[^\w]=', $s, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $words = [];

  foreach ($w as $word) {
    if (!isset($words[$word])) $words[$word] = 0;
    $words[$word]++;
  }
  print_r($words);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [lorem] => 2
    [ipsum] => 1
    [dolor] => 1
    [sit] => 2
    [amet] => 1
    [consectetur] => 1
    [adipiscing] => 1
    [elit] => 1
    [sed] => 1
    [do] => 1
    [eiusmod] => 1
    [tempor] => 1
)
```

Is that what you're looking for?